# When should I use glitch traps?

Tags: heat-signature

In what scenarios should I be using glitch traps? I know I can use them to teleport enemies outside of their ship, but what other uses are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best uses for it that I've found:

- Being able to space any enemy is no small feat, especially if you have no other way to deal with armored/shielded enemies.
- Very useful for putting in a choke point or near a large group of guys, then luring them into it.
- You can throw unconscious people into glitch traps, which can be useful for rescue/capture missions.
- If you're nowhere near the edge of the ship, use one to get a lot of guys into the same room. Bunched up guys are easier to get with explosives, shotguns, slipstreams, etc.
- Use a glitch trap to move someone (even an unconscious someone) on the other side of a wall, then use a swapper to take their place. Great way to get somewhere you couldn't otherwise get to.
- Lay a glitch trap a little in front of the airlock, if you get ko'd and carried to the exit, it will teleport your holder away (assuming they take you back to that same airlock).
- I haven't tested this but sticky grenades might go with a guy when he's glitched.

Comment: There's a lot of great suggestions here that I'll have to try!